# How to recognize the urls in the text in android?

Tags: android

For eg, I have to set the text as

```
setText("Please check this link for you reference "http://www.test.com ");
```

How to make the above url as clickable url.i.e recognize that text as url and directs to that page.

Comment: What you have tried.. did you search the forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [setAutoLinkMask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:autoLink="web"` in your `TextView` or `EditText` of your xml file whichever you are using.